# Is it possible to run Camera2 in Picture-in-Picture in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera2

If it is, how can I continue camera preview on SurfaceTexture inside PiP?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Take a look at the [PiP guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture) for the general details, but you should be able to keep a TextureView in a PiP window just fine, and have the camera API send data to it.